# IntelliJ 13 - Add Navigate Back/Forward to toolbar?

Tags: intellij-idea, navigation, ide, toolbar

Jetbrains changed the toolbars in IntelliJ 13.

The Navigate Back & Forward arrows, shown here, used to be in the top toolbar and easily clickable.

[image: back/forward]
Now the only way I can find to access these fields is to go to Navigate -> Back or Navigate -> Forward.

Does anyone know of a way to add these back/forward locations into an **always visible** toolbar like they were located in IntelliJ 12?

Comment: I had this problem too.  You can just enable the toolbar with View > Toolbar, but that takes up loads of room, and now the run configurations are shown in the same bar as the breadcrumbs, this is the only thing that's missing when it's hidden.  It'd be great if these buttons were included in the breadcrumbs bar when the toolbar is hidden.

Comment: UPDATE: OK, you can do this.  Turn the toolbar on, with View > Toolbar.  Right click it, and choose "Customize Menus and Toolbars".  In the "Navigation Bar Toolbar" folder, add the icons from Main menu > Navigate > Back / Forward, choose OK, then go and turn off the toolbar with View > Toolbar again.

Comment: Similar answer can be found at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76950256/5059725)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I am using Idea 13 and my toolbar already has these buttons:

[image: IntelliJ 13 Toolbar]

The icon groups are:

file | undo/redo | cut/copy/paste | font size | back/forward | compile/run | vcs | config | help | jira | tasks

You should be looking at the back/forward buttons in the 5th group.

If you want to make the toolbar visible, it's one of the checkable options on the view menu.

Answer (score 204):

For some reason the toolbar is not visible by default.

In the View menu, select Toolbar. That should fix it.

Comment: I really don't get it why they decide to hide one of the most used features in a next version! Common guys!

Comment: May be they decide to break the product and then sell again old features) The very poor tactic seems very popular nowadays... Like hiding Firefox toolbars by default i nnew versions etc.
Thanks again, Rob Mayhew!

Comment: In version 2021.1 of PHPStorm, it is `View > Appearance > Toolbar`

Answer (score 53):

### IntelliJ IDEA 15

#### Show toolbar

- **Method 1**

  - View > Toolbar

    [image]
- **Method 2**

  - Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> 2 times > write "toolbar" and click on the "switch button" to change "OFF" in "ON":

    [image]

The toolbar already contains the "Back" and "Forward" buttons.

#### Configure toolbar

- **Method 1**

  - File > Settings... > Appearance & Behavior > Menus and Toolbars > Main Toolbar > select one row and click on "Add After..." if you want to add a new button (E.g.: if you accidentally removed the Forward button and you want it back)

    [image]
    [image]
    [image]
- **Method 2**

  - Right click on the toolbar > Customize Menus and Toolbars...

    [image]
  - Use the approach that is described in Method 1

Answer (score 37):

To enable toolbar in intellij 2019.3,

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Just go to the "View" tab and check-enable "Toolbar"

***be noted that shortcut keys(ctrl+alt+ left/right) are not working**

Answer (score 12):

For newer versions, the image illustrates below

[image: Rider]

Comment: +10, for taking time out and putting it in the GIF format. it really helped.

Answer (score 10):

Here is just a reference image, where to find the top right bar in the settings. [image: IntelliJ]

(Note: This is PyCharm)

Answer (score 5):

The Conan's answer helped me with the same issue. 2Conan - make your comment as an answer. It helps with TS issue. Just for sure posting his answer here ...

OK, you can do this. Turn the toolbar on, with `View > Toolbar`. Right click it, and choose `Customize Menus and Toolbars`. In the `Navigation Bar Toolbar` folder, add the icons from `Main menu > Navigate > Back / Forward`, choose OK, then go and turn off the toolbar with `View > Toolbar` again.