# Back and forward navigation arrow icon gone

Tags: android-studio

There used to be two little blue back and forwards navigation arrow icons in the Android Studio toolbar that provided navigation between recent source files I was editing. Now, for some reason, this little navigation arrow is gone. Any idea how to get it back or what it's called? Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Found the answer

> For some reason the toolbar is not visible by default.
>   In the View menu, select Toolbar. That should fix it.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432143/intellij-13-add-navigate-back-forward-to-toolbar)

Answer (score 8):

From Android Studio 4.0 you can go at the menu:
**View -> Appearance -> Toolbar**

Answer (score 5):

Follow steps:

```
1.) File --> Settings --> Appearance & Behavior --> Menus and Toolbars.
2.) Top Search bar -> Type Navigate -> expand navigate menu -> you will find 2 options "Back" and "Forward".
3.) Drag "Back" option to main menu called "Main Toolbar Left".
4.) Drag "Forward" option to main menu called "Main Toolbar Left".
5.) click on Apply. Then it will start appear back and forward menu icons on main toolbar left side.
```