# How to show back/forward buttons in the new Android Studio Giraffe (2022.3.1) UI/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

The new layout for Android Studio is nice, but it seems like they left out one of the most important buttons! The back and forward buttons were always at the top, where did they go?

[image: Android Studio toolbar w/ no nav buttons]

I've looked in every menu item, file, and help, but it seems to have just disappeared.

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-303358/NewUI-toolbar-customization-add-back-forward-navigation-buttons#focus=Comments-27-6765005.0-0 for the detailed steps to get the buttons back.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ 13 - Add Navigate Back/Forward to toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432143/intellij-13-add-navigate-back-forward-to-toolbar)

Comment: @jeprubio No, they've completely removed the old Toolbar option. Now we have to do this other route just to add buttons that should be enabled by default...

Comment: But there is a gif in an answer in there for the new ui with the same

Comment: @jeprubio Oh, I see that now. But I wrote this with the intention of helping others with the same issue I was going through. I didn't see that answer because it specifies IntelliJ 13, and I wanted to make it clear that this answer is to help users of the new interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not crazy, the back/forward buttons are disabled by default. If you right click on the toolbar along the existing buttons, you'll be able to access a menu called "Customize Toolbar".

[image: Android Studio right click customize]

From there, select the "+" at the top", select "Add Action", either navigate to Main Menu > Navigate > Back/Forward or search for "Back/Forward", and then select both of them to add them to the menu bar. You can even add a separator beforehand to make it look more organized!

[image: Android Studio add action selection]
Hope this helps someone because this has been driving me crazy!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which buttons you mean, but did you try right clicking on the toolbar, then going to `Customize Toolbar` and then adding action with the `+` button? I guess you should find it there.

[image: Toolbar customizing]